# Why there is no traffic goes through to my server, however firewall setup correctly?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016 in a provides (actually it is a VPS), where an Azure Storage Emulator runs and I would like to connect to it from local machine. It uses port 10000, when I test my app just hangs and timeouts. When I try to call the endpoint via browser (http://IP_ADDRESS:10000) I got the page is not available error. However, if I call from the server the http://localhost:10000, then I get an error message provided by the emulator. There is a  [PortQry](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e596d2c6-812d-4cfa-a04a-cefc8965ae17/how-to-check-if-a-port-on-the-server-is-open-for-a-outgoing-traffic-and-b-incoming-traffic?forum=winserversecurity) stuff testing a given port it says the port does not listen. I cannot telnet to the given port.

```
netstat -aon shows the following:
 TCP    127.0.0.1:10000        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10002        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

The windows firewall has rules to let traffic through these ports, and it is restarted.

I tried to telnet to the given ports from another machine, it did not work.

I already run out of ideas what can be the problem. Why it does not work? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What I notice in your netstat output, it is just listening to the loopback interface.
 Could you try binding it to 0.0.0.0